# Use awk to split line into array and use that array's values in calling shell

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

I am trying to use `awk` inside a `bash` script and do a rather common task:  iterate well structured file lines and split them by a delimiter into an array.  Here is a sample from the file:

```
Joe:Johnson:25
Sue:Miller:27
```

There are numerous examples how this can be done on a single line in the interactive mode, however, I am doing it in a script in which I would like to use that array manipulated by awk outside the awk subshell in bash itself:

```
cat ${smryfile} | while read smryline; do

    echo ${smryline}

    #now i want to split the line into array 'linearray' in awk but have it usable when i get back to bash
    echo ${smryline} | awk '{split($0,$linearray,":")}'

    varX=$linearray[2]
    echo $varX
    #do something with $varX

done
```

I get an error:

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> {split($0,$linearray <<< ,":")}
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do (use arrays that are defined in awk outside of its scope) and how should I do it?

Comment: Please note that `${var}` is not the same as `"$var"`. Verify with this: `var="    a     b    c    "; echo "$var"; echo ${var}` -- you'll see the whitespace removed in the 2nd echo.

Comment: You try to split a line into an awk array, and then try to access that array under the same name as shell variable! That won't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you can do what you want without awk:

```
cat "${smryfile}" | while IFS=: read first last varx
do
    echo "first='$first' last='$last' varx='$varx'"
    # do something
done
```

This produces:

```
first='Joe' last='Johnson' varx='25'
first='Sue' last='Miller' varx='27'
```

Note that this approach will work even if some names in the file include spaces.

Note also that the use of `cat` above is not necessary:

```
while IFS=: read first last varx
do
    echo "first='$first' last='$last' varx='$varx'"
    # do something
done <"${smryfile}"
```

A side benefit of removing `cat`, as per the above, is that any variables that you create in the loop will survive after the loop finishes.

Comment: i found the same solution simultaneously and it works.  thanks

Comment: +1, neat solution for this use-case, although no arrays were assigned as was the original question.

Comment: This is good information, but it doesn't *technically* answer the question, since it doesn't assign to an array, and thus is entirely un-scalable.

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
linearray=($(awk -F: '{$1=$1} 1' <<<"${smryline}"))
echo ${linearray[2]}
# output: 27
```

Explanation: `awk -F:` splits input on `:`. `awk` by default separates modified output with a space, so you can construct an bash array directly with the output from `awk`. Note *modified output*, hence the no-op call to `$1=$1`, else the data would just come out in the original form.

But given your example, why not extract the third column with `awk -F:` and loop the output:

```
awk -F: '{print $3}' "$smryfile" | while read varX; do
    echo $varX
done
```

Comment: doesn't really work.  the array doesn't get the expected data

Comment: @amphibient - right, I missed a no-op "hack" when testing and copy-pasting. Updated.

Comment: I understand that `{$1=$1}` is a no-op action, but I am not understanding the role of the lone '1' that follows without an intervening `;`.

Comment: @Codex24 it's just `awk` shorthand for `print`. The same thing could be written like this: `{{$1=$1;} print;}`.

Comment: @Codex24 - The general pattern in `awk` is `condition {action} condition2 {action2} ...`. The default action is `print $0`, and `1` evaluates to `true`, so `awk '1' file` is the equivalent of `cat file`. The point of `{$1=$1}` is to make `awk` believe a field was changed, else it would print the input unchanged including the `:` which we want to get rid of to create the bash array.

Answer (score 0):

Granted you did ask for a solution with `awk`, but I think the `sed` solution is a bit more clear.

```
str="Joe:Johnson:25"
array=($(echo "$str" | sed 's/:/ /g'))
for el in "${array[@]}"; do
    echo "el = $el"
done
```

This gives:

```
el = Joe
el = Johnson
el = 25
```

In this case, you have to be sure not to put double quotes around the command expansion, so you don't end up with a single string element.

And this doesn't work for elements that contain spaces, of course.  If you had:

```
str="Joe:Johnson:25:Red Blue"
```

You'd end up with

```
el = Joe
el = Johnson
el = Red
el = Blue
```

But if you don't mind using `eval`, you can insert quotes before the array assignment to get it to work.

```
eval "array=($(echo "\"$str\"" | sed 's/:/" "/g'))"

# Before the eval, it turns into:
eval "array=("Joe" "Johnson" "25" "Red Blue")"
```